Suppose $(X,Y)$ have copula $C(u,v)$, does $(aX,aY)$ have the same copula for $a>0$?
Suppose $(X,Y)$ have copula $c(u,v)$ in the sense of $Pr(X\leq x,Y\leq y)=Pr(F_X(X)\leq F_X(x),F_Y(Y)\leq F_Y(y))=Pr(U\leq u, V\leq v)=c(u,v)$,
where $u\equiv F_X(x)$ and $v\equiv F_Y(y)$ and $c(u,v)$ is the copula function. My question is: does scaling $(X,Y)$ change the copula function?  Mathematically it seems that the copula function would not change because $Pr(aX\leq x,aY\leq y)=Pr(F_X(X)\leq F_X(x/a),F_Y(Y)\leq F_Y(y/a))=Pr(U\leq u', V\leq v')=c(u',v')$,
which is the same copula function evaluated at a different point $(u',v')$ (due to scaling of the original point $(x,y)$), but the function $c(\cdot,\cdot)$ still remains unchanged. Intuitively, the copula function should not change either because copula is about the correlation in ranks between (X,Y) and scaling does not change the ranks. Am I right?

What is the joint distribution of $(aX, aY)?$

Yes this is correct. Let $G$ be the cdf of $(aX, aY)$. Since $F_{aX} (x)= F_X (x/a)$ we can conclude
\begin{align}
G(x, y) &= \Pr(aX\leq x,aY\leq y) \\
&= \Pr(X\leq x/a,Y\leq y/a) \\
&= C(F_X(x/a), F_Y(y/a)) \\
&= C(F_{aX} (x), F_{aY} (y))
\end{align}
so $C$ is a Copula for the scaled vector.

Thank you very much! This is very helpful! Seems this result also generalize to $(g(X),h(Y))$ for strictly increasing functions $g(\cdot)$ and $h(\cdot)$, right? That's to say, strictly increasing transformations of two random variables do not change the copula?

@ExcitedSnail Yes, the proof should work exactly the same way. The copula encodes dependence excluding the marginals and the transformations you describe just change the marginals.
